# Sync work between 2 systems using git with free account on github?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github.

I have a free account on github.

My question/requirement is that I need to keep sync the work from one system to other.For example in leisure I try to learn technologies/frameworks through tutorials and I need to be independent of the system(start the code on work system from where I left on my home system and vice versa).

Does a free account on github allows to do so. If yes then how can I get started with it?
If not is there any other system that allows this?

I am sorry if this query is not according to SO question rules, but I need to start somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you can just push to the Github repo from one machine, and pull from the other.

Comment: Thanks Oli, for the comment, Can I do push and pull from both the machines?

Comment: @Mozak of course. Read a git book or tutorial. This is basic stuff that you need to learn. And you won't learn it by asking questions here. http://git-scm.com/book/en

Comment: @Mozak: the easiest way is to push/pull via ssh. You can create a new user for that and create a bare repository or you can add a more complicated installation. Example: http://www.fclose.com/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/

Comment: You can also use an existing account, see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167905/git-clone-through-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the free account on git to do this.
The main limitation with the free github account is no private repositories.

You can push and fetch from both machines.
You can use branches for features (and/or all changes) and push those branches to/from github.
You can pull (or merge / rebase) on both machines.

You can also use services like Dropbox and Google Drive that will sync the files for you without thought.  These can be good if you will be the only developer.

You can also combine these, e.g. copy files into your Dropbox for a week while commuting back and forth and then at the end of the week put them in a (non-Dropbox) git project.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer.