# Git - get repo clone address

Tags: git

On a remote AWS server, I have created a git repo inside a folder.
Now I need the http adress to clone the project from my local computer. But I haven't found any git method to show me this address.  Is there such a method?

I tried an address but it says `fatal: repository (..) not found`.

Here is what I do basically:

I am logged by SSH as ubuntu. (ubuntu has a folder at `/home/ubuntu` if this matters)

The webpage is at: `/var/www/webpage.com/`

My git project is at `/var/www/webpage.com/thing`

So what I have tried locally is this: `git clone https://webpage.com/thing.git`

What would be the correct clone addres?

Comment: These comments make absolutely no sense. Why would you ask about HTTP when he is clearly "logged by SSH as ubuntu"? Also, a git server? Telling someone to use a third-party service for cloning a repository? Reported.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming server name to be `server` and user name `user`.

On your server run:

```sh
cd ~
git init --bare testrepo
```

On your personal machine:

```sh
git clone user@server:testrepo.git/
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134428/11615853) for more details on absolute paths vs paths relative to your home folder like I used.